# Vector Iterator causes Segmentation Fault 11 while attempting Depth First Search on a graph

Tags: c++, c++11, depth-first-search

I am attempting to use DFS based on a vector iterator to compute the largest connected cluster of a generated graph. However when the graph is a certain size (seeding probability above 0.4) a segmentation fault 11 occurs at the DFS function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

float seedingProbability = 0.6;
int latticeSize = 1024;
int graphSize;
bool *visited;
long largestClusterSize = 0;

std::vector<int> *graph;
std::vector<int> currentCluster;

std::uniform_real_distribution<float> unif(0, 1);
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 rand_engine(rd());

//Is a random number between 0 and 1 higher than (1-seeding probability)
bool isCriticalThreshold() {
    float r = unif(rand_engine); //a random float between 0 and 1
    bool isCritical = r > (1-seedingProbability);
    return isCritical;
}

//This helper function is used to determine the site index
int siteFor(int x, int y) {
    return (latticeSize*x)+y;
}

//Add an undirected edge to the graph between two sites
void addEdge(int site1, int site2) {
    graph[site1].push_back(site2);
    graph[site2].push_back(site1);
}

void DFS(int v) {
    visited[v] = true;
    currentCluster.push_back(v);

    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = graph[v].begin(); it != graph[v].end(); it++) {
        if(!visited[*it]) {
            DFS(*it);
        }
    }
}

void connectedComponents() {
    for (int i=0; i < (graphSize); i++) {
        visited[i] = false;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<(graphSize); i++) {
        if (visited[i] == false) {
            currentCluster.clear();
            DFS(i);

            long clusterSize = currentCluster.size();
            if (clusterSize > largestClusterSize) {
                largestClusterSize = clusterSize;
            }
        }
    }
}

void createGraph() {
    for (int x = 0; x < latticeSize; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < latticeSize; y++) {
            //Down bond
            if (isCriticalThreshold()) {
                if (y == latticeSize-1) { addEdge(siteFor(x, y), siteFor(x, 0)); }
                else { addEdge(siteFor(x, y), siteFor(x, y+1)); }
            }

            //Right bond
            if (isCriticalThreshold()) {
                if (x == latticeSize-1) { addEdge(siteFor(x, y), siteFor(0, y)); }
                else { addEdge(siteFor(x, y), siteFor(x+1, y)); }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Running..." << std::endl;

    graphSize = latticeSize*latticeSize;
    graph = new std::vector<int>[graphSize];
    visited = new bool[graphSize];

    createGraph();
    connectedComponents();

    std::cout << "Largest cluster: " << largestClusterSize << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I based the DFS on: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/connected-components-in-an-undirected-graph/

Comment: There are some issues with using raw pointers here. For example, `bool *visited` is just a pointer to a `bool`, not a `bool` array. I'd replace it with `std::vector<bool>`. Second, `std::vector<int> *graph` is a pointer to a vector, not a vector of vectors (which is what I think you want). I'd replace it with `std::vector<std::vector> graph`. Third, in `DFS (int v)`, you are marking the node as visited, but there is no distinction between a leaf node and any other nodes. There is a very simple DFS algorithm [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) which might be of use.

Comment: @cantordust I totally agree with your suggestion of using standard container, but please note that the OP actually allocates enough memory using `new` (but never deletes, though). Apart from that, it remains an unjustified use of (global!) raw pointers.

Comment: @Bob__ Indeed, you are right. This was a half-baked comment on my side!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jszpilewski has pointed out, the main problem is that you are probably running out of stack memory. A recursive algorithm like DFS can fill up the stack very quickly. You can use a non-recursive DFS algorithm with explicitly managed stack.

I have put together a sample program based on your code to illustrate the point. I have taken the liberty of replacing raw pointers with objects and arrays with `std::vector`s. I think that this is much safer in terms of memory management. Each node is a simple `struct` with (optional) coordinates `x` and `y` as locations on the lattice. The main change is in `DFS()`, which explicitly manages a stack for each unvisited node. Please feel free to edit this to suit your needs. I have tested the code with `latticeSize` up to 4096, and it works. Note that `Node` objects only need to store edges to all target nodes but not to source nodes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <functional>
#include <stack>

class Node;
typedef std::reference_wrapper<Node> NodeRef;

float seedingProbability = 0.8;
size_t latticeSize = 4096;
size_t largestClusterSize = 0;

std::vector<size_t> clusters;
std::vector<std::vector<Node>> graph;

std::uniform_real_distribution<float> unif(0.0, 1.0);
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 rand_engine(rd());

struct Node
{
    size_t x;
    size_t y;

    bool visited;

    std::vector<NodeRef> targets;

    // Add edges
    void addEdge(Node& _target)
    {
        targets.emplace_back(_target);
    }

    explicit Node(size_t _x, size_t _y)
        :
          x(_x),
          y(_y),
          visited(false)
    {}
};

// Is a random number between 0 and 1 lower than the seeding probability
bool isCriticalThreshold()
{
    return unif(rand_engine) < seedingProbability;
}

void DFS()
{
    for (auto& row : graph)
    {
        for (auto& node : row)
        {
            node.visited = false;
        }
    }

    for (auto& row : graph)
    {
        for (auto& node : row)
        {
            if (!node.visited)
            {
                size_t clusterSize(0);
                std::stack<NodeRef> stack;
                stack.push(node);
                while (!stack.empty())
                {
                    Node& cur_node(stack.top());
                    stack.pop();
                    if (!cur_node.visited)
                    {
                        cur_node.visited = true;
                        ++clusterSize;
                        for (auto& tgt : cur_node.targets)
                        {
                            stack.push(tgt);
                        }
                    }
                }

                clusters.push_back(clusterSize);
            }
        }
    }
}

void connectedComponents() 
{

    largestClusterSize = 0;
    for (const auto& clusterSize : clusters)
    {
        if (clusterSize > largestClusterSize)
        {
            largestClusterSize = clusterSize;
        }
    }
}

void createGraph()
{
    // Generate the lattice
    for (size_t x = 0; x < latticeSize; ++x)
    {
        graph.emplace_back(std::vector<Node>());
        for (size_t y = 0; y < latticeSize; ++y)
        {
            graph.back().emplace_back(x, y);
        }
    }

    // Add edges
    for (size_t  x = 0; x < latticeSize; ++x)
    {
        for (size_t y = 0; y < latticeSize; ++y)
        {
            // Down bond
            if (isCriticalThreshold())
            {
                graph.at(x).at(y).addEdge(graph.at(x).at((y + 1) % latticeSize));
            }

            // Right bond
            if (isCriticalThreshold())
            {
                graph.at(x).at(y).addEdge(graph.at((x + 1) % latticeSize).at(y));
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::cout << "Running..." << std::endl;

    createGraph();
    DFS();
    connectedComponents();

    //  std::cout << "Cluster sizes:\n";
    //  for (size_t c = 0; c < clusters.size(); ++c)
    //  {
    //      std::cout << "\tCluster " << c << ": " << clusters.at(c) << "\n";
    //  }

    std::cout << "Largest cluster: " << largestClusterSize << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Stack overflow is the most typical problem when running a recursive DPS on a large graph. In your case you are also building an auxiliary data collection `currentCluster` so check out if you are not running out of 32 bit memory space for your program (about 2-4 GB depending on OS). Hence if you are indeed compiling in 32 bit mode try generating and testing a 64 bit version of your program.

Comment: I've tried running the same code without `currentCluster` and it still results in a segmentation fault. About 55mb of memory is typically used by the process when it crashes.